# how to have loading in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, loading, splash-screen

my MainActivity contains a ViewPager that loads 4 fragments, each fragment should load lots of data from the server.

so when my app wants to be run for the first time, it almost takes more than 3 seconds and the other times(for example, if you exit the app but not clean it from your 'recently app' window and reopen it) it takes almost 1 second.

while it is loading, it shows a white screen.

is there any way instead of showing a white screen till data become ready, I show my own image?
something like the splash page?

Comment: Your layout should have an alternate view to show while it’s loading. The list view should be hidden. Then swap the visibility when the data is ready to display. You need to load your data in a background asynchronous task so you don’t risk getting an ANR. This can be done easiest by using coroutines in a ViewModel for the data. Too much to explain here but there are many tutorials you can find.

Comment: thanks for your response, unfortunately, I'm not completely familiar with android and I'm improving my skills. can you suggest me a tutorial?

Comment: There are a variety of topics here. I would start with the official android documentation on ViewModel. I'll post a quick overview below when I have time.

Comment: thanks a lot.@Tenfour04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do long-running actions on the main thread, you risk getting an [ANR crash](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr).

Your layout for each fragment should have a loading view that is initially visible, and your data view. Something like this:

(*not code*)

```
FrameLayout
    loading_view (can show a progress spinner or something, size is match parent)
    content_view (probably a RecyclerView, initial visibility=GONE, size is match parent)
/FrameLayout
```

You need to do your long running action on a background thread or coroutine, and then swap the visibility of these two views when the data is ready to show in the UI.

You should not be directly handling the loading of data in your Fragment code, as Fragment is a UI controller. The Android Jetpack libraries provide the ViewModel class for this purpose. You would set up your ViewModel something like this. In this example, MyData could be anything. In your case it's likely a List or Set of something.

```
class MyBigDataViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {

    private val _myBigLiveData = MutableLiveData<MyData>()
    val myBigLiveData: LiveData<MyData>() = _myBigLiveData 

    init {
        loadMyBigData()
    }

    private fun loadMyBigData() {
        viewModelScope.launch { // start a coroutine in the main UI thread
            val myData: MyData = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) { 
                // code in this block is done on background coroutine
                // Calculate MyData here and return it from lambda
                // If you have a big for-loop, you might want to call yield()
                // inside the loop to allow this job to be cancelled early if
                // the Activity is closed before loading was finished.
                //...
                return@withContext calculatedData
            }

            // LiveData can only be accessed from the main UI thread so
            // we do it outside the withContext block
            _myBigLiveData.value = myData
        }
    }

}
```

Then in your fragment, you observe the live data to update the UI when it is ready. The below uses the `fragment-ktx` library, which you need to add to your project. You definitely should read the [documentation on ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).

```
class MyFragment: Fragment() {

    // ViewModels should not be instantiated directly, or they won't be scoped to the
    // UI life cycle correctly. The activityViewModels delegate handles instantiation for us.
    private val model: MyBigDataViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        model.myBigLiveData.observe(this, Observer<MyData> { myData ->
            loading_view.visibility = View.GONE
            content_view.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            // use myData to update the view content
        })
    }
}
```